# evenly distributing duplicates throughout a randomized list (playlist shuffle)

Tags: random, shuffle, playlist

I need to shuffle about 1,000 strings of the form "title - artist", where a number of the titles repeat (say "Silent Night"), and a number of the artists repeat (say, "Bing Crosby").  None of the "title - artist" combos repeat, and there are no additional hyphens.

I'd like to end up with a list with as much space as possible between identical titles and between identical artists.

I'm leaning toward just randomly shuffling the whole list many thousands of times, and keeping whichever one has the greatest distance between the closest pair of identical repeats.

Another brute force: shuffle (just once) then repeat tons of times: find the closest pair and swap one of them into a different random spot.

One seem better than the other?  Anything a little smarter, but still easy?

Thanks a ton!

Comment: "I'd like to end up with a list with as much space as possible between identical titles and between identical artists." Then it wouldn't be random. This would force such things to cluster towards the beginning and end of the list. As a first step, you need to decide just what it is that you want to do. My hunch is that you have a rough idea, but to design an algorithm you need a specific criterion.

Comment: A third possibility is to specify a minimum allowable between such repeats and randomly shuffle until that threshold is satisfied. A sticking point is that for some combinations of parameters this might be either impossible or vanishingly unlikely to achieve. As a safety valve, have a timeout which in that case returns your first option. This is a natural question that confronts anyone who wants to write a humanly-satisfying shuffle feature for playlists. See [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/194480/233981) (from [softwareengineering.se]) for some other ideas.

Comment: Do you have few example strings to paste? May be 50- 100 strings?

Comment: @JohnColeman: You should post your comments as an answer, and perhaps quote part of the question you linked to.  In general, answers to questions should not appear as comments.

Answer (score 0):

Perfect John Coleman!  Thank you!
Identical question, with suggestions, here:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/194480/233981

------------  EDIT  ------------

I couldn't be happier with my result!

Contrary to the op (me) I ignored repeated artists.  Two "Bing Crosby"s in a row really doesn't matter compared with two "White Christmas"s.

I took the most popular song and spread it evenly across an unpopulated array.  Then the second most popular song and did the same, incrementing past any collisions with #1.  Repeat through the entire list, including songs with 0 repeats filling in the last empty slots.

So every 34th track is (a different) "Silent Night" (#1), which is impossible to detect as a listener.  Every 46th track is "White Christmas" (#2, starting at a different location, with collisions bumped to 1 past "Silent Night")....

For the listener it couldn't be more random, and has zero of the gotcha/repeats I always get with rand(), noise(), and all of their sisters. ;)

Something like this:

```
populate the result list with null's
for each unique title, sorted from greatest # of repeats -> fewest # of repeats {
    perfectSpacing = list.size() div (number of times this title repeats)
    i = random(list.size())  // random starting location for this title
    for each unique version of this title {
        while (list[i] != null) // bump past populated slots, wrapping around
            i = (i + 1) % list.size()
        list[i] = current version of the current title
        i = (i + perfectSpacing) % list.size()
        // jump the ideal distance for the next version of this title
    }
}
```

Although "bumping past collisions" introduces the risk of wrapping around and creating a back-to-back repeat, the number of repeats in the data set are too few to allow it.  Almost half of them don't repeat at all, and for those that do repeat, the curve from "lots of repeats" to "only a few repeats" degrades very rapidly.

Hope that help somebody some day!